# Need to use sql result an input criteria on a chart

Tags: php, sql, charts

I have PHP webpage that does a call to sql db an returns a result below:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "useraccounts");
$sql = "SELECT expense from ctincome";

if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    echo "<table id>";
        echo "<tr>";

            echo "<th></th>" ;
            echo "</tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td style=\"font-size:40;\">".$row['expense']." 
   </td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    // Free result set
    mysqli_free_result($result);
  } else{
    echo "We could not retrieve your details";
  }
  } else{
  echo "ERROR: Could not execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
  }
```

I want to use the result as an input parameter in a google chart below (in the sections " parameter 1" and "parameter 2") how do i express the sql result in a manner the google chart will allow as a parameter ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = chart.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Graph', 'Income to Expense'],
      ['Income',     parameter 1],
      ['Expense',    parameter 2]

    ]);

    var options = {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      title: 'Expenses to Income Ratio',
      is3D: true,
    };

    var chart = new 



 </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
     google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]}); google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
     function drawChart() { 
    var data = chart.visualization.arrayToDataTable([ ['Graph', 'Income to Expense'],

    <?php

    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "useraccounts"); 
    $sql = "SELECT expense from ctincome"; 
    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)       { 
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 

    echo "['Income', ' ".$row['income']." ']";
    echo "['Expense',' ".$row['expense']." ']";



     }  mysqli_free_result($result); } else{
     //echo "We could not retrieve your details";
     } 
    } 
    else{ 
   // echo "ER
```

}

```
     }  mysqli_free_result($result); } else{
    // echo "We could not retrieve
```

}

```
?>

    ]); 

    var options = { backgroundColor: 'transparent', title: 'Expenses to Income Ratio', is3D: true, }; 
    var chart = new 
    </script>

// hint just like u drawing data from table
```